# CSS change color of child span when parent is active

Tags: css

Iam working in `Jquery mobile`I have an footer like this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer" data-tap-toggle="false">     
            <div class="footer" data-role="navbar">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#dashboard" data-icon="dashboard" class="footer-icons" id="icon-dashboard">
                    <span class="navbar-text">Dashboard</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#notifications" data-icon="progress" id="icon-progress" class="footer-icons">
                    <span class="navbar-text">Voortgang</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#map" data-icon="security" id="icon-security" class="ui-btn-active footer-icons">
                    <span class="navbar-text">Plattegrond</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" data-icon="security" id="icon-security" class="footer-icons">
                    <span class="navbar-text">Securitycheck</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>   
            </div>
          </div>
```

I want to change the color of `<span class="navbar-text"></span>` when its parent is set to active I thought something like this:

```
.footer > .ui-btn-active > .navbar-text {
    color: red!important;
}
```

But this is not working maybe someon could help me out on this?

Comment: what do you mean by active?

Comment: '>' says to target direct children only, not nested children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `.ui-btn-active` is not a child of `.footer` as the `>` requires - it's a grandchild. Remove that operator:

```
.footer .ui-btn-active > .navbar-text {
    color: red !important;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8mLyz33y/)

Alternatively if you want to use the child selector, you need to explicity set the full hierarchy in the selector:

```
.footer > ul > li > .ui-btn-active > .navbar-text {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Also note that the use of `!important` should be avoided at all costs. If you need to override a setting, make the selector more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I like the :nth-child(n) selector:

```css
a.ui-btn-active > span:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
```